# When traversing nested object and using match to give filtered object results in javascript it returns array of [object], [object] etc

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

**Context** I am using:
Windows 11, VSCode and node v18.12.1

The code I am working on is trying to traverse several JSON objects. Then, using an array variable, the code needs to filter on certain attributes in each object, as there is more than one value that needs to filter against in each name attribute in each object.

**Question** The following code is working which traverses all levels of all objects and logs the person's name, city and employer. What it needs to do is also filter out all objects that match one or more of the names in the filteredNames array, and then return all objects where they don't contain these names.

Here is the code that's working (as per above):

```js
let data = [{
    "Pagination": {
        "NumberOfPeople": 185,
        "PageSize": 200,
        "PageNumber": 1,
        "NumberOfPages": 1
    }, 
    "People": [
    {
    "name": "TJ",
    "job": "Software Engineer",
    "organization": {
        "company": {
        "employer": "amazon",
        "department": "IT"
            }
        },
    "location": {
    "city": "Boston",
    "state": "Massachusetts"
    }
},
{
    "name": "Dominique",
    "job": "CEO",
    "organization": {
        "company": {
        "employer": "IBM",
        "department": "IT"
            }
        },
    "city": "Seattle",
    "state": "Washington",
},
{
    "name": "Enrique",
    "job": "Engineer",
    "organization": {
        "company": {
        "employer": "Bellkrieg Megasystems",
        "department": "Construction"
            }
        },
    "location": {
    "address": {
    "state": "New York",
    "city": "New York City",
    "zip": "11323"
        }
    }
},
{
    "name": "Bob",
    "job": "Project Manager",
    "organization": {
        "company": {
        "employer": "Megasystems",
        "department": "R&D"
            }
        },
    "address": {
        "location": {
            "quadrant": {
                "block": 1,
                "state": "Texas",
                "city": "Austin"
            }
        }
    }
}
]}]

data.filter(item => {
    iterateObject(item);
});

function iterateObject(obj) {
    for(prop in obj) {
        if(typeof(obj[prop]) == "object"){
            iterateObject(obj[prop]);
        } else {
            if(prop == "name" || prop == "city" || prop == "employer") {
            console.log(prop.toUpperCase() + ': ', obj[prop]);
            }
            //some code goes here which if either of filteredEmployers is in 'employer', nesting position agnostic, i.e. the attribute could be nested deeper or shallower in the object, 
            //then print out all objects which don't contain any of the attributes in filteredEmployers array
        }
    }
}
```

**which gives the result:**

```json
NAME:  TJ
EMPLOYER:  amazon
CITY:  Boston
NAME:  Dominique
EMPLOYER:  IBM
CITY:  Seattle
NAME:  Enrique
EMPLOYER:  Bellkrieg Megasystems
CITY:  New York City
NAME:  Bob
EMPLOYER:  Megasystems
CITY:  Austin
```

Using an array variable, it needs to filter on 'Megasystems' and 'Bellkrieg' as an array in each object's employer attribute, as there is more than one value that needs to be filtered against. It will also make it more adaptable, so it will be relatively easy to add to the filteredEmployers, as and when it's required...

**What I've tried**
I've searched various other solutions for the issue encountered, but they don't seem to cater for what is needed...

This is what I currently have...

```js
//data of nested objects goes here

filteredEmployers = ['Megasystems', 'Bellkrieg'];

data.filter(item => {
    iterateObject(item);
});

function iterateObject(obj) {
    for(prop in obj) {
        if(typeof(obj[prop]) == "object"){
            iterateObject(obj[prop]);
        } else {
                            
                checkPeople = Object.values(data).filter(({employer}) =>
    !filteredEmployers.some(filtered => employer?.match(filtered)));
                if(checkPeople !== null) {
            console.log(checkPeople);}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, it gives the following:

```json
    [
      {
        Pagination: {
          NumberOfPeople: 185,
          PageSize: 200,
          PageNumber: 1,
          NumberOfPages: 1
        },
        People: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
      }
    ]
    [
      {
        Pagination: {
          NumberOfPeople: 185,
          PageSize: 200,
          PageNumber: 1,
          NumberOfPages: 1
        },
        People: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
      }
    ]
    [
      {
        Pagination: {
          NumberOfPeople: 185,
          PageSize: 200,
          PageNumber: 1,
          NumberOfPages: 1
        },
        People: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
      }
    ]
    [
      {
        Pagination: {
          NumberOfPeople: 185,
          PageSize: 200,
          PageNumber: 1,
          NumberOfPages: 1
        },
        People: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
      }
    ] // etc etc 30 times
```

Pagination shouldn't be returned, and the People objects should return all attributes of the People not in the filteredEmployers list, not the `People: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object]`

The result I'm after is as follows (or pretty similar):

```json
{
    "name": "TJ",
    "job": "Software Engineer",
    "organization": {
        "company": {
        "employer": "amazon",
        "department": "IT"
            }
        },
    "location": {
    "city": "Boston",
    "state": "Massachusetts"
    }
},
{
    "name": "Dominique",
    "job": "CEO",
    "organization": {
        "company": {
        "employer": "IBM",
        "department": "IT"
            }
        },
    "city": "Seattle",
    "state": "Washington",
}
```

Any advice appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpret your question to mean that you want to produce an array of "People" objects, but filter out the ones whose nested "employer" property is a string which includes a substring that is one of the ones in your filter list.

If that's correct, you can do it this way:

```js
function transform (array, employerFilterList) {
  const people = array.flatMap(o => o.People);
  return people.filter(person => {
    const employer = person?.organization?.company?.employer;

    // If the person has no employer field,
    // then the restricted employer filter doesn't apply,
    // so include the person:
    if (typeof employer !== 'string') return true;

    // Else...
    const employerIsNotFiltered = employerFilterList.every(
      str => !employer.includes(str)
    );

    return employerIsNotFiltered;
  });
}

const json = `[{"Pagination":{"NumberOfPeople":185,"PageSize":200,"PageNumber":1,"NumberOfPages":1},"People":[{"name":"TJ","job":"Software Engineer","organization":{"company":{"employer":"amazon","department":"IT"}},"location":{"city":"Boston","state":"Massachusetts"}},{"name":"Dominique","job":"CEO","organization":{"company":{"employer":"IBM","department":"IT"}},"city":"Seattle","state":"Washington"},{"name":"Enrique","job":"Engineer","organization":{"company":{"employer":"Bellkrieg Megasystems","department":"Construction"}},"location":{"address":{"state":"New York","city":"New York City","zip":"11323"}}},{"name":"Bob","job":"Project Manager","organization":{"company":{"employer":"Megasystems","department":"R&D"}},"address":{"location":{"quadrant":{"block":1,"state":"Texas","city":"Austin"}}}}]}]`;
const data = JSON.parse(json);

const filteredEmployers = ['Megasystems', 'Bellkrieg'];
const result = transform(data, filteredEmployers);

console.log(result); // [{name: "TJ", ...}, {name: "Dominique", ...}]
```

References:

- [Optional chaining (`?.`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)
- [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)
- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [`Array.prototype.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)
- [`String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Comment: Thanks for this - it works and is useful. I wondered if there was a way that it could work regardless of the employer property's nested position, or be nesting position agnostic, i.e. this would mean the employer could be nested deeper or shallower in the object, but still print out all objects which don't contain any of the attributes in filteredEmployers array. At the moment, using optional chaining, it's assuming the depth of the employer property will always be the same - this might not always be the case. Then again, this could be another question. Thoughts?...

Comment: [^](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=33774353) @e-driver1 Sure: that’s possible. It’s also not a criteria you listed in the question. Asking concise and clear questions is a skill that takes practice, and none of the data that you presented suggests the new information you asked about. If you’d like to try to update the question with data that represents all the actual possibilities, I can revise my answer. Alternatively — if you feel this answers your question — you can mark it as such and ask a new one. And if you want to link me to it here, I’d be glad to take a look.