# json API response code using flatmap not working javascript

Tags: javascript, json

**Problem**
I’m trying to return only the objects that don’t contain any of the names on the filteredEmployers list, against the employer attribute, from an API I'm retrieving the data from.

**What I've tried**
I have an alternative piece of code that seems to work fine when I don’t connect to the API (i.e. reading from hardcoded data), but when I connect to the API, even though I get the following response (when immediately logged after retrieval), the code then doesn’t execute…

```
{
    "Pagination": {
        "NumberOfPeople": 185,
        "PageSize": 200,
        "PageNumber": 1,
        "NumberOfPages": 1
    },
    "People": [
        {
            "name": "TJ",
            "job": "Software Engineer",
            "organization": {
                "company": {
                    "employer": "amazon",
                    "department": "IT"
                }
            },
            "location": {
                "city": "Boston",
                "state": "Massachusetts"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Dominique",
            "job": "CEO",
            "organization": {
                "company": {
                    "employer": "IBM",
                    "department": "IT"
                }
            },
            "city": "Seattle",
            "state": "Washington"
        },
        {
            "name": "Enrique",
            "job": "Engineer",
            "organization": {
                "company": {
                    "employer": "Bellkrieg Megasystems",
                    "department": "Construction"
                }
            },
            "location": {
                "address": {
                    "state": "New York",
                    "city": "New York City",
                    "zip": "11323"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Bob",
            "job": "Project Manager",
            "organization": {
                "company": {
                    "employer": "Megasystems",
                    "department": "R&D"
                }
            },
            "address": {
                "location": {
                    "quadrant": {
                        "block": 1,
                        "state": "Texas",
                        "city": "Austin"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The code I’m trying to implement is here:

```
// constants and variables are defined here, including API credentials and the filteredEmployers array
//FYI const filteredEmployers = ['Megasystems', 'Bellkrieg'];
//the code then fetches the API data is here
.then((response) => {
    return response.json();
})
.then((json) => {
    //console.log(typeof json);
    //console.log(json);
    const people = Array.from(json).flatMap(o => o.People);
    return people.filter(person => {
        const employer = person?.organization?.company?.employer;

        if (typeof employer !== 'string') return true;
        const employerIsNotFiltered = filteredEmployers.every(
            str => !employer.includes(str)
        );
        console.log("This is the outputted data: " + employerIsNotFiltered);
        return employerIsNotFiltered;
    });
})
```

The desired response is:

```json
[
  {
    name: 'TJ',
    job: 'Software Engineer',
    organization: { company: [Object] },
    location: { city: 'Boston', state: 'Massachusetts' }
  },
  {
    name: 'Dominique',
    job: 'CEO',
    organization: { company: [Object] },
    city: 'Seattle',
    state: 'Washington'
  }
]
```

Any recommendations on how to get this to execute, or alternatives to this method appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: your indentation appears random, can you fix it?

Comment: @gog can you elaborate? Which indentation? Is Javascript indent sensitive? Didn't think it was...

Comment: javascript is indeed not indent-sensitive. We are ;)

Comment: btw, the problem appears to be with: `Array.from(json)`. `json` is an object, not an array.

Comment: This appears to be related to OP's previously-asked question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74604459/438273

Comment: On that note: just change `const people = Array.from(json).flatMap(o => o.People);` to `const people = json.People;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reiterating my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74632635/json-api-response-code-using-flatmap-not-working-javascript#comment131739347_74632635) on your question: You just need to change the line

```js
const people = Array.from(json).flatMap(o => o.People);
```

to

```js
const people = json.People;
```

The JSON response that you included in the question is an object, and [`Response.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json) returns a promise which resolves to an already parsed representation of the JSON text response, so in order to access the array at the `People` property, you only need `json.People`. Here is a runnable snippet based on the code and data that you showed:

```js
// The JSON data, copied and pasted from the first code block of your question:
const json = `{"Pagination":{"NumberOfPeople":185,"PageSize":200,"PageNumber":1,"NumberOfPages":1},"People":[{"name":"TJ","job":"Software Engineer","organization":{"company":{"employer":"amazon","department":"IT"}},"location":{"city":"Boston","state":"Massachusetts"}},{"name":"Dominique","job":"CEO","organization":{"company":{"employer":"IBM","department":"IT"}},"city":"Seattle","state":"Washington"},{"name":"Enrique","job":"Engineer","organization":{"company":{"employer":"Bellkrieg Megasystems","department":"Construction"}},"location":{"address":{"state":"New York","city":"New York City","zip":"11323"}}},{"name":"Bob","job":"Project Manager","organization":{"company":{"employer":"Megasystems","department":"R&D"}},"address":{"location":{"quadrant":{"block":1,"state":"Texas","city":"Austin"}}}}]}`;

function mockFetch () {
  return Promise.resolve({
    json: () => Promise.resolve(JSON.parse(json)),
  });
}

const filteredEmployers = ['Megasystems', 'Bellkrieg'];

mockFetch()
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    // Change this line:
    // const people = Array.from(json).flatMap(o => o.People);

    // To:
    const people = json.People;

    return people.filter(person => {
      const employer = person?.organization?.company?.employer;

      if (typeof employer !== 'string') return true;
      const employerIsNotFiltered = filteredEmployers.every(
        str => !employer.includes(str)
      );

      return employerIsNotFiltered;
    });
  })
  .then(console.log);
```

Comment: That's hit the nail on the head. Just so I can play around with the response, beyond logging it, I have replaced ```then(console.log);``` with ```.then((employerIsNotFiltered) => {
                console.log("now creating and writing the file");
                fs.writeFileSync('./script10_test1.json', JSON.stringify(employerIsNotFiltered, null, "\t"));
                console.log("finished creating the file");
            });```